# Excel Vlookup Formula Troubleshooting

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm goofing a bit on the syntax here.

But in most basic terms, if sheet 'CT', column B has a corresponding lookup value in column B of sheet 'CT WKSHT'  AND column K of 'CT WKSHT' is N/A (this cell is a formula that will not always have a value) then I want to populate a 1 else a 0.

The formula below is sort of conceptually what I'm trying to do, but I'm not doing this right clearly.

Please help if you can, as I get stuck when I think about getting vlookups to have additional conditions on them.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CT!B4,'CT WKSHT'!B8:K8,10,FALSE),1,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you even working with `VLookup()`? If I read your formula, it reads like:

- Look for a value in column B and if you find it, return the value of column K.

  - If the lookup did not work, then show 1
  - If the lookup did work, then show and empty string

Why do you want to return value of column K if you overwrite it with an empty string anyway?

I would advise you the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CT!B4,'CT WKSHT'!B8:K8,10,FALSE),1)
```

Is this better?

Also, you are looking for that value just on row 8, why not for the whole range:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CT!B4,'CT WKSHT'!B:K,10,FALSE),1
```

Comment: Question, so I had it slightly flipped (and this is my bad).. if the lookup to column B finds a row, AND the value of the corresponding lookup row Column K of the 'CT WKSHT' is #N/A , then I want it populate a 1 else I want it to be blank.  I will aggregating on this column later (summing up all of the 1's)

Comment: @Amateurhour35: in that case, I'm afraid that you'll need to add another `IfError()` function: one to cover the `vlookup()` and one to cover the K column value.

Comment: IF(AND(VLOOKUP(CT!B4,'CT WKSHT'!B:K,1,FALSE)=CT!B4, IFERROR(vlookup(CT!B4,'CT WKSHT'!B:K,10,FALSE)),1,0)    <-- Is this sort of what I need to do?  Trying to figure out how to get the syntax right

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. It combines a normal IF statement with ISERROR. ISERROR simply returns True or False depending on the result of the VLOOKUP.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(DCTM!B4,'DCTM WKSHT'!B:K,10,FALSE)),1,0)
```